YT-DLP and FFMPEG standalone video downloader
I am trying to create a video downloader that can download only from youtube.com and vimeo.com.
I can get the script to work fine on my machine, both running from the IDE and the pyinstaller .exe, but running the .exe I created on another machine gives a FileNotFoundError.
I am missing some knowledge that I need to go and learn about. Any advice or this is appreciated.
I have tried including the ffmpeg.exe and yt-dlp.exe in their own folders, so folder structure is as follows:

main.exe
ffmpeg

ffmpeg.exe


yt-dlp

yt-dlp.exe



I am using main.spec to build the executable with pyinstaller, I have included both main.py and main.spec below
main.py:
import os
import platform
import subprocess
import sys

def get_videos_path():
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        return os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Videos')
    elif platform.system() == 'Darwin':
        return os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'Movies')
    else:
        raise Exception('Unsupported operating system.')

def sanitize_filename(filename):
    return "".join(c for c in filename if c.isalnum() or c in (' ', '.', '_')).rstrip()

def get_ffmpeg_path():
    # find the ffmpeg executable. 
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # If the application is run as a bundle
        if platform.system() == 'Windows':
            return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'ffmpeg', 'ffmpeg.exe')
        else:
            return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'ffmpeg', 'ffmpeg')
    else:
        # If the application is run as a script
        if platform.system() == 'Windows':
            return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'ffmpeg', 'ffmpeg.exe')
        else:
            return 'ffmpeg'  # Adjust for other systems if necessary

def download_video(url, output_path):
    if not os.path.exists(output_path):
        os.makedirs(output_path)

    # Construct yt-dlp command
    command = [
        'yt-dlp', 
        '--impersonate', 'Safari',  # Ensure impersonation target is specified
        '--format', 'bestvideo+bestaudio/best',  # Format selection
        '--merge-output-format', 'mp4',  # Merge formats into mp4
        '--ffmpeg-location', get_ffmpeg_path(),  # Specify FFmpeg location
        '--output', os.path.join(output_path, '%(title)s.%(ext)s'),  # Output template
        url
    ]

    # Ensure FFmpeg is correctly detected
    ffmpeg_path = get_ffmpeg_path()
    print(f"FFmpeg path: {ffmpeg_path}")
    os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + os.path.dirname(ffmpeg_path)
    print(f'''Video downloading now, and will be output to {output_path}.
        The console will close automatically when the video is downloaded.''')
    try:
        # Execute the yt-dlp command
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print(f"Video downloaded and merged successfully to {output_path}")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

# Actual script, get user input and run the commands
video_url = ""
while 'youtube.com' not in video_url.lower() and "vimeo.com" not in video_url.lower():
    video_url = input("Please paste the video url here. Youtube or Vimeo only: ")
output_path = get_videos_path()
download_video(video_url, output_path)

main.spec:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('ffmpeg', 'ffmpeg')],
    hiddenimports=['yt_dlp'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)

